# Is the Amazon .NET AWS SDK's AmazonS3 thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is the Amazon .NET AWS SDK's `AmazonS3` thread safe or should I be creating a new instance of `AmazonS3` per request in a multi-threaded system?

Specifically for the latest .NET AWS SDK (version 1.3.14).

Comment: You can determine this on your own.  if the main ui thread is blocked while a request is being worked out then its not thread safe.  I have never heard the term "client thread safe" before

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see how thread safety and a blocking API are related. Also there might not even be a ui thread, for example if the client is a console application. So your comment makes even less sense.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the comment, I had incorrectly worded the title and question. When working with the `AmazonS3` object I think of it as the "`AmazonS3` client", I did not mean "client thread safe" as a collective term.  The question and title have now been adjusted. As for your suggestion - I'm not sure if that can be used to judge "thread safeness".  E.g. if I create a function with locks inside it, when you call it, it will block while waiting for the lock but it may well be thread-safe in that multiple threads could call it without its internal shared data/state getting "damaged".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I also asked this question on the Amazon AWS forum and an official AWS employee replied (Norm@AWS) with:

> The .NET SDK is thread safe so keeping an instance of any of the
>   clients like AmazonS3 around and reusing them is fine.
>
> Norm

Link ([Amazon .NET Development Forum - Is the .NET SDK's AmazonS3 thread safe?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=78026&tstart=0)).

Comment: Could someone confirm that this is still true? Answer has 10 years :)

Comment: Some additional information can be found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1544