# Cannot access a disposed object when running function more than once

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application and I am getting the error:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client'

when trying to call my AWS S3 read object service.  This service works the first time and fails on the second and subsequent times.

I have the following in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAWSService, AWSService>();
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

(I have tried configuring AsScoped() to no effect.)

This is the function that is causing problems:

```
public class AWSService : IAWSService
{
    private readonly IAmazonS3 _s3Client;

    public AWSService(IAmazonS3 s3Client)
    {
        _s3Client = s3Client;
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> ReadObjectFromS3Async(string bucketName, string keyName)
    {
        try
        {
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName
            };

            using (_s3Client)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                using (var getObjectResponse = await _s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                    getObjectResponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(ms);
                }
                var download = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");

                return download.FileContents;
            }

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

The first time I run the function, a breakpoint shows that this.s3client is not disposed, however subsequent attempts at running this function show that the s3client is disposed, hence the error.

**Update**

I'm calling this function from a controller:

```
public class CorrespondenceItemController : Controller
{
    private IAWSService _awsService;

    public CorrespondenceItemController(IAWSService aWSService)
    {
        _awsService = aWSService;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult<dynamic>> Send([FromBody]CorrespondenceItemSendViewModel model)
    {

        var attachment = await _awsService.ReadObjectFromS3Async(bucket, key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you wrap the `_s3Client`'s usage in a `using` block, which disposes the instance afterwards.

Don't do that.

Let your IoC container handle that for you, by not explicitly or implicitly disposing your `_s3Client`.

It's fine to register your wrapper as a singleton, given the answer to [Is the Amazon .NET AWS SDK's AmazonS3 thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743488/is-the-amazon-net-aws-sdks-amazons3-thread-safe) is "yes". This means that your application has one instance of your `AWSService` at any given time, and that class will be using the same instance of `IAmazonS3` for all requests.

Then you only need to dispose it at the end of your application lifetime, and your IoC container will handle that.

Comment: Ok, all the documentation I've found has recommended the using block.  I've updated my question in case I'm doing something obviously wrong!

Comment: The documentation I found recommended singleton

Answer (score 2):

Using is shorthand for a try/finally block that calls dispose.

Answer (score 1):

This line `using (_s3Client) { }` is saying, create a client and execute the code within the braces { }. Then call `.Dispose()` to close it.

This means that your client will be closed/shutdown depending on what the `Dispose()` method does.

If you want to keep the connection open then you should not have a `using` block, or alternatively you could change your injected client into a client factory and have it create a new one each call, or manually open/close the connection each time you use it.

Comment: Ok... what's the best way to modify the code then so that I can avoid my issue?

Comment: It depends on the best practices for using the s3 Client, but you can simply remove the `using` statement to stop it disposing the client afterwards. That should work. However check the documentation because it might be that you need to create a new client for every call, or do something similar to that.

Comment: Ok, all the documentation I've found has recommended the using block.  I've updated my question in case I'm doing something obviously wrong!

Comment: In that case, it is likely recommending you create a new client each time, OR within the using block, there will be a command to re-open the connection. In fact a cursory look at google suggests creating a new client within the using block for each call. For example, `using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2)) { ... }`. So if you wanted to use dependency injection you'd have to use a factory.

Answer (score 1):

```
 using (_s3Client){}
```

once  `using` block complete execution then dispose method will be called

using statement equal to

```
  var ob = new Object()
 try
 {
   ob = null;
 }
 finally
 {
  if (ob!= null)
    ((IDisposable)ob).Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Ok, all the documentation I've found has recommended the using block.  I've updated my question in case I'm doing something obviously wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Remove using _s3Client, which is getting disposed as you kept it inside a using block. As your objective is to reuse it, do not dispose, simple.

```
using (var getObjectResponse = await _s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    getObjectResponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(ms);
    FileContentResult download = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
    return download.FileContents;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, only problem is that ms.ToArray is showing an error as ms is not defined (it's only available in the using block)

Comment: Oops my bad. Glad you spotted

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to use your s3Client as Singleton, remove **using** line. This way, you will have a s3Client object through your application lifetime. Be carefull if s3Client stores any object in it. It may cause a resource problem.

  public class AWSService : IAWSService
  {
      private readonly IAmazonS3 _s3Client;

  ```
  public AWSService(IAmazonS3 s3Client)
  {
      _s3Client = s3Client;
  }

  public async Task<byte[]> ReadObjectFromS3Async(string bucketName, string keyName)
  {
      try
      {
          GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
          {
              BucketName = bucketName,
              Key = keyName
          };

              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

              using (var getObjectResponse = await _s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
              {
                  getObjectResponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(ms);
              }
              var download = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");

              return download.FileContents;

      }
      catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
      }
      return null;

  }
  ```

  }
- If you want to create a new object for every call, remove s3Client registration from IOC context.

  public class AWSService : IAWSService
  {

  ```
  public async Task<byte[]> ReadObjectFromS3Async(string bucketName, string keyName)
  {
      try
      {
          GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
          {
              BucketName = bucketName,
              Key = keyName
          };

          using (var s3Client= new s3Client()/*I don't know how you create*/)
          {
              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

              using (var getObjectResponse = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
              {
                  getObjectResponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(ms);
              }
              var download = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");

              return download.FileContents;
          }

      }
      catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
      }
      return null;

  }
  ```

  }