# Using same instance of AmazonS3Client for parallel request?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, .net-4.7.2, aws-sdk-net

I have the code below to download multiple files from S3 in parallel using AmazonS3Client. This has been working fine.

```
public async Task Download(IList<string> urls, int maxConcurrentDownloads)
{
        var output = new List<Stream>();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
        {
            
            AmazonS3Uri s3Uri = null;
            if (AmazonS3Uri.TryParseAmazonS3Uri(urls[i], out s3Uri))
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                output.Add(ms);
                tasks.Add(GetObject(s3Uri,ms));
            }

            if (tasks.Count == maxConcurrentDownloads || i == urls.Count - 1)
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                tasks.Clear();
            }
        }                        
}

private async Task GetObject(AmazonS3Uri s3Uri, Stream output)
{
    using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(s3Uri.Region))
    {
       // removed for brevity purpose
       await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(...);
    }
}
```

All URLs are in the same region. The code above creates new instance of `AmazonS3Client` for each URL.  So I refactored the code to use single instance of `AmazonS3Client`.

```
public async Task Download(IList<string> urls, int maxConcurrentDownloads)
{
        var output = new List<Stream>();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        using(AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
            {
                AmazonS3Uri s3Uri = null;
                if (AmazonS3Uri.TryParseAmazonS3Uri(urls[i], out s3Uri))
                {
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    output.Add(ms);
                    tasks.Add(GetObject(s3Client,s3Uri,ms));
                }

                if (tasks.Count == maxConcurrentDownloads || i == urls.Count - 1)
                {
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    tasks.Clear();
                }
            }
       }            
}

private async Task GetObject(AmazonS3Client s3Client, AmazonS3Uri s3Uri, Stream output)
{
    // download file using provided s3Client
    await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(...);
}
```

**Questions**

1. Given maxConcurrentDownloads = 20, is it advisable to use single instance of S3Client to download or upload in parallel?
2. The default value for `AmazonS3Config.ConnectionLimit` is 50, does that mean single instance of S3Client can concurrently download or upload 50 files?
3. Or better yet, should I use the Singleton instance of Amazons3Client?

Any recommendations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AmazonS3Client Single connection Vs new connection for each call C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145548/amazons3client-single-connection-vs-new-connection-for-each-call-c-sharp)

Comment: According to this dup [AmazonS3Client Single connection Vs new connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64145548/9664), the client maintains a pool of `HttpClient`s. With the potential bottleneck being credential resolution. See link for more info...